# c# datagridview adding check box to data column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a gridview that contains data.  I want the user to be able to toggle certain data, which will trigger an event to the database.

I have implemented this, with a single check box column that toggles information for a row at a time.

however, I now have the need to be able to toggle specific columns within each row.  Is it possible to somehow include a checkbox in specific data cells or would I simply have to have a checkbox column next to each column that I want to toggle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to display more than one checkbox for a row (on one of the columns cells as  your requirements) you can use the RowDataBound event of the gridview: it allows to change the value of the cell before the grid is rendered. Here's a sample : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can add a checkbox into a column of your dataGridView

just go to `Add Column property`

then select `type of Column` to `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`